# Chrome Breakpoint for changing focus isn't working

Tags: debugging, google-chrome

So I am working on an issue where on load an item is gaining focus and I don't want this to happen, I am attempting to figure out why this is happening.

so I go into chrome and set the Event Listener Breakpoints for focus and DOMfocusIn/focusOut, but it doesn't seem to matter, the page will load, and I will see the anchor tag (used for a button) gain focus right after, but it doesn't trigger the breakpoint.

What is more weird is that when I break on load of the page and resume it, it no longer gains focus (although everything else seems to work fine)

Why does hitting a break point prevent focus?
and Why does it not hit a break point when I set the event listener to focus?
is there a way to give focus unintentionally? (ie. without an obvious focus function call)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug, I found a way to figure this out. essentially I added an onFocus function to anchor tag in question and made an alert with the following code:

```
alert(arguments.callee.caller.toString());
```

This shows who was calling the onFocus, and it actually worked, so I think this means it is a chrome specific bug.

I had to add the onFocus with javascript due to the code being in a taglib and no onFocus attribute available, but it worked.